# Form Collection with choice field

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form to modify an entity which has some children entities. I use a form collection to do so. When I edit this entity, the children collection should appear but it doesn't. The children collection is composed of 2 choice fields and 1 integer field. The integer field is well rendered with the right data but choice fields ask to select an option whereas it should show Matiere and Colle of children entities.

In the code, Colle entity is a child of Matiere Entity. I'm using MaterializeCSS as a framework.

Here's my code :

Child Form :

```
 $builder
        ->add('matiere', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Matiere',
            'attr' => ['class'=> 'matiere'],
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'label' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une matière',
            'mapped' => false])
        ->add('colleEnfant', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'PACESColleBundle:Colle',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'colles'],
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'label' => false,
            'group_by' => 'matiere',
            'required' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'choose.colle'])
        ->add('ordre', IntegerType::class,[
            'attr'=>['class'=>'ordre'],
            'required' => true,
            'label' => false]);
```

Parent Form :

```
$builder->add('nom', TextType::class,['label' => 'Nom de la colle'])
    ->add('collesEnfants', CollectionType::class,
        ['label' => false,
        'entry_type' => SousColleFormType::class,
        'required' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false]);
```

View :

```
<table id="tableau" class="creneaux"
               data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.collesEnfants.vars.prototype)|e }}">

   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Matière</th>
          <th>Colle</th>
          <th>Ordre</th>
          <th>Supprimer</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
       {% for colle in form.collesEnfants %}
          <tr>
             <td>{{ form_row(colle.matiere) }}</td>
             <td>{{ form_row(colle.colleEnfant) }}</td>
             <td>{{ form_row(colle.ordre) }}</td>
             <td><a href="" class="delete_colle_link"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></td>
          </tr>
       {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.matiere').material_select();
        $('.colles').material_select()
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The field render is ok? You just wonder why existing data not selecting in choice box?

Comment: Field rendering is ok. As you said, only problem is existing data not selected in choice fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it with JQuery.

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for colleEnfant in collesEnfants %}
         $('#paces_colle_colle_ajoutsupercolle_collesEnfants_{{ loop.index0 }}_matiere option[value="{{ colleEnfant.matiere }}"]').prop('selected', true);
         $('#paces_colle_colle_ajoutsupercolle_collesEnfants_{{ loop.index0 }}_colleEnfant option[value="{{ colleEnfant.colle }}"]').prop('selected', true);
    {% endfor %}
    $('.matiere').material_select();
    $('.colles').material_select();
}
```

Controller :

```
$collesEnfantsForm = [];
foreach ($colle->getCollesEnfants() as $colleEnfant) {
     $collesEnfantsForm[] = ['matiere' => $colleEnfant->getMatiere()->getId(), 'colle' => $colleEnfant->getId()];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query in your entity type and check if the field 'nom' exist in your entity.

```
$builder->add('colleEnfant', EntityType::class, [
    'class'        => 'PACESColleBundle:Colle',
    'attr'         => ['class' => 'colles'],
    'choice_label' => 'nom',
    'label'        => false,
    'required'     => true,
    'placeholder'  => 'choose.colle',
    'query_builder' => function(ColleRepository $repository) {
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c');
        // the function returns a QueryBuilder object
        return $qb->groupBy('c.matiere')->orderBy('c.nom', 'ASC');
    }
])
```

After you need to add an event listener who detect the select modification.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $matiere = $this->em->getRepository('PACESColleBundle:Matiere')->find($data['matiere']);
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $form->add('colleEnfant', EntityType::class, [
        'class'        => 'PACESColleBundle:Colle',
        'attr'         => ['class' => 'colles'],
        'choice_label' => 'nom',
        'label'        => false,
        'required'     => true,
        'placeholder'  => 'choose.colle',
        'query_builder' => function(ColleRepository $repository) use ($matiere) {
            $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c');
            // the function returns a QueryBuilder object
            return $qb
                ->where('c.matiere = :matiere')
                ->setParameter('matiere', $matiere)
                ->orderBy('c.nom', 'ASC');
        }
    ]);
});
```

I hope this going to help you.

Comment: Actually, I have data in my choice field which are all Colle Objects grouped by Matiere. What I want is to have all Colle which already are in children Collection to be selected in choice fields.

Comment: There is a relation One to Many with Matiere and Colle ?

Comment: Yes. And a self-referencing OneToMany relationship in Colle Entity

Answer (score 0):

it is because ArrayChoiceList::getValuesForChoices() does comparison for objects by reference. As result if you have not same instance of object in data and  in list of choices that it won't be selected. Solution is to use "choice_value" options for ChoiceType field. eg.

```
   $builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => FeeType::getTypes(),
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'required' => true,
                'choice_value' => static function (?FeeType $feeType) {
                    return $feeType ? $feeType->getId() : '';
                }
            ])
```